# Closing an emberfire/torii session and logging out throws permission_denied errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire, torii

I am using EmberFire with the Torii for sessions. I am getting an odd issue when I log a user out, and the following errors are thrown in the console:

```
firebase.js:186 Error: permission_denied at /folders/-KKvrk3K_JOHxQWgR1km: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:186(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:380Tb @ firebase.js:276uc @ firebase.js:263vc @ firebase.js:262(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:449vh @ firebase.js:434g.wd @ firebase.js:425Ye.wd @ firebase.js:328(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:326vd @ firebase.js:279La.onmessage @ firebase.js:278
firebase.js:186 Error: permission_denied at /folders/-KLFp3zh5QUB7KvMF0HZ: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:186(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:380Tb @ firebase.js:276uc @ firebase.js:263vc @ firebase.js:262(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:449vh @ firebase.js:434g.wd @ firebase.js:425Ye.wd @ firebase.js:328(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:326vd @ firebase.js:279La.onmessage @ firebase.js:278
firebase.js:186 Error: permission_denied at /externalApps/-KLF_wKXtzm38EHtuQ_C: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:186(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:380Tb @ firebase.js:276uc @ firebase.js:263vc @ firebase.js:262(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:449vh @ firebase.js:434g.wd @ firebase.js:425Ye.wd @ firebase.js:328(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:326vd @ firebase.js:279La.onmessage @ firebase.js:278
firebase.js:186 Error: permission_denied at /users/-KLKUOZRBCIeCj44WMe7: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:186(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:380Tb @ firebase.js:276uc @ firebase.js:263vc @ firebase.js:262(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:449vh @ firebase.js:434g.wd @ firebase.js:425Ye.wd @ firebase.js:328(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:326vd @ firebase.js:279La.onmessage @ firebase.js:278
firebase.js:186 Error: permission_denied at /externalApps/-KLIyXUwTSrkCIL4rz7U: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

There are two places where I login a user:

**At Registration**

```
register(data) {
  return this.get('firebaseApp')
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then((registeredUser) => {
      const newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
        uid: registeredUser.uid,
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName,
        email: registeredUser.email
      })
      return newUser.save();
    })
    .then((savedUser) => {
      return this.get('session').fetch().then(() => {
        return savedUser;
      });
    })
    .then((savedUser) => {
      this.replaceWith('dashboard');
    });
}
```

**For an already registered user**

```
login(email, password) {
  const controller = this.controllerFor('index');
  this.get('session').open('firebase', {
    provider: 'password',
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then((/* response */) => {
    controller.set('loginError', undefined);
    this.replaceWith('dashboard');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    controller.set('loginError', error);
  });
}
```

And here is the action that logs the user out:

```
logout() {
  this.get('session').close().then(() => {
    this.store.unloadAll();
    this.replaceWith('index');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this very same issue about a week ago.  It seems that the way Emberfire implemented there Ember Data extensions do not allow for the use of `store.unloadAll()`

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/400) but haven't seen any responses from the team.

You can easily work around this issue by unloading the user directly from the store.  As long as you use the `store.unloadRecord(<specificRecord>)` or `<specificRecord.unload()` then everything works fine.

In your case you could save the user record when logging in or registering a new user and then unload that record on logout.  If all of those actions aren't in the same controller, you would probably have to create a service to handle that interaction.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

After 2 years the error still exists :)
So really *quick and dirty* solution to avoid the errors in the console. Regarding to [this](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/400#issuecomment-319218329) comment the "emberfire never stops listening to any record after its loaded". So to "disconnect" from the Firebase server we can simply open (I mean full app[=page] reload) the page without any emberdata elements.
So my solution (whatever palace in the app):

```
actions: {
    signOut: function () {            
        window.location.replace('/login');
    }
}
```

On login route:

```
beforeModel(){
    if (this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated')) {            
        this.get('session').close()
    }
}
```

Some information about my setup:

DEBUG: Ember      : 3.1.3

DEBUG: Ember Data : 3.1.1

DEBUG: Firebase   : 3.9.0

DEBUG: EmberFire  : 2.0.10

DEBUG: jQuery     : 3.3.1

Hope this will help to avoid errors on the page. Maybe bad idea if app is really big.

Answer (score 0):

The key to @Paul's answer is:

```
actions: {
  signOut: function () {            
    window.location.replace('/login');
  }
}
```

If you're using Emberfire and Torii provider, then you'll need to refetch the session to be able to close it. This is what I'm doing in my `sign-out` route...

```
export default Route.extend({
  session: inject(),
  redirect() {
    get(this, 'session')
      .fetch()
      .then(async () => {
        await get(this, 'session').close();
        this.transitionTo('/sign-in');
      });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

I setup a controller in this route so that I can show a loading spinner while the app is fetching the session.